# XSLT Get the node value by index in foreach loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file here:

```
<TestBlock number="534" result="ok" text="READDTC_POSTDVT">
            <TestStep datatype="A" result="ok" text="Open Link">
              <StringResult format="ascii" value="BSM" />
            </TestStep>
            <TestStep datatype="A" result="ok" text="BCM DTC Read">
              <StringResult format="ascii" value="REQ" />
            </TestStep>
          </TestBlock>
          <TestBlock number="511" result="ok" text="READDTC_POSTDVT">
            <TestStep datatype="A" result="nok" text="Open Link">
              <StringResult format="ascii" value="CCU" />
            </TestStep>
            <TestStep datatype="A" result="nok" text="BCM DTC Read">
              <StringResult format="ascii" value="REQ" />
            </TestStep>
          </TestBlock>
```

My result I expect is
in each TestBlock I just want to get the 1st StringResult@value (example: BSM, CCU)
should be:

```
<OP_VAL KEY="BSM" VALUE="okBSM"/>
<OP_VAL KEY="BSM" VALUE="okREQ"/>
<OP_VAL KEY="CCU" VALUE="nokCCU"/>
<OP_VAL KEY="CCU" VALUE="nokREQ"/>
```

My xslt but it doesnot work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Telegram/Body/Data/ResultData/TestResult/TestBlock">
    <xsl:for-each select="TestStep">
        <xsl:element name="OP_VAL">
            <xsl:attribute name="KEY">
                <xsl:value-of select="/Telegram/Body/Data/ResultData/TestResult/TestBlock[1]/StringResult/@value"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@result,StringResult/@value)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `for-each` changes the context node and you probably want to select `../TestBlock[1]/StringResult/@value` instead of `/Telegram/Body/Data/ResultData/TestResult/TestBlock[1]/StringResult/@value`.

Also note that `xsl:element` is only needed to compute an element name or namespace at run-time, otherwise use literal result elements e.g. `<OP_VAL KEY="{../TestBlock[1]/StringResult/@value}" VALUE="{@result}{StringResult/@value}"/>`

Comment: thank you so much. it worked perfectly. I used ../TestStep[1]/StringResult/@value